# Async Storage movie watchlist in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

its my first time i create an APP for my study project , i created app of database of movies using TMDB API , and it remain one last step to finish my project , and it's creating WatchList or Plan to Watch , and i have no idea how to make it .  please can someone who have idea of how to create it with Async Storage or anything to save watchlist, and where to add it?
I will put my code

this code of Movie screen, and i need a touchableopacity that make save the movie into favorite component

````
   import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';


import {
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  Linking,
  ImageBackground,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
  FlatList
} from 'react-native';
import {IMAGE_POSTER_URL} from '../config';
import {GET} from '../../Services/API';
import Loader from '../Components/Loader';
import Constants from '../Components/Constants';
import TrendingMovies from '../Components/TrendingMovies';
import TrendingPeople from '../Components/TrendingPeople';
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import PeopleDetails from '../Components/PeopleDetails.js';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import {POSTER_IMAGE} from '../config';

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';


const deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;


const MovieDetails = props => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [details, setDetails] = useState();
  const [favourites, setFavourites] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getDetails = async () => {
      const data = await GET(`/movie/${props.route.params.movieId}`);
      setDetails(data);
      setLoading(false);
    };

    getDetails();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getVideo = async () => {
      const results = await GET(`/movie/${props.route.params.movieId/videos}`);
      setDetails(results);
      setLoading(false);
    };

    getVideo();
  }, []);



  const getGenre = () => {
    return details.genres.map(genre => (
      <View >
        <Text style={styles.genre}>{genre.name}</Text>
      </View>
    ));
  };


    return (
    <View style={styles.sectionBg}>
      
      

      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (

       <View style={{ flex: 1 }} >
            <Image
              source={{uri: `${IMAGE_POSTER_URL}${details.backdrop_path}`}}
              style={styles.imageBg}
            />
      <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between', alignItems:'center', marginRight:15, marginTop:10}}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()}
            style={{  marginLeft:20, marginTop: 20, marginBottom:20}} 
            >
            <Image
     source={require("../../assets/icons/back.png")}
          style={{ width:93/1.4 , height: 50/1.4 }} />

           </TouchableOpacity>

           <TouchableOpacity  
            style={{  marginLeft:20, marginTop: 20, marginBottom:20}} 
            >
            <Image
     source={require("../../assets/icons/nolicked.png")}
          style={{ width:256/5.7 , height: 252/5.7 }} />

           </TouchableOpacity>
           </View>

      <ScrollView style={{ flex:1 ,}} >
       
          
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                  Linking.openURL('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${details.key}');
                }}
                  style={{ marginTop:240, marginLeft: "70%",zIndex:1 }}
                > 

                
          <Image
     source={require("../../assets/icons/youtube.png")}
          style={{ width: 75, height: 75}} />
          </TouchableOpacity>



 <ImageBackground
     source={require("../../assets/icons/hmm.png")}
          style={{ width:'100%' , height: '84%',zIndex:-1 ,marginTop: -60,marginBottom:20}} >
          
          <View  style={{  alignSelf: 'center' , marginTop:40 }} >
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row' }} >
          <Image
     source={{uri: `${IMAGE_POSTER_URL}${details.poster_path}`}}
          style={{ width: 150/1.2 , height: 220/1.2 , borderRadius: 20, marginTop: 40 , marginLeft: 20, zIndex:1 }} />
          <View style= {{flexDirection:'column' , }} >
          <Text style={styles.detailsMovieTitle}>{details.title}</Text>
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row' , alignItems: 'center', marginLeft: 15 , backgroundColor:'orange' , width:70, marginVertical: 5, borderRadius:10}} >
          <Image
     source={require("../../assets/icons/star.png")}
          style={{ width: 20, height: 20 , marginLeft: 5, marginVertical:8}} />
          <Text style= {{color:'#20222A' , fontSize: 18, marginLeft: 6, fontWeight:'bold' ,marginRight: 15}} >{details.vote_average}</Text>
          </View>

          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', width: 80 ,marginTop:25, marginLeft:20}}>
            {getGenre()}
          </View>
          <Text style={{marginLeft: 14,
                       marginHorizontal:-5,
                       marginVertical:5,
                       fontWeight:'bold',
                       color: '#C3C3C3',
                       fontSize: 10,}}>{details.runtime} Minutes</Text>
    <Text style={{marginLeft: 14,
    marginHorizontal:-5,
    color: '#C3C3C3',
    fontWeight:'bold',
    fontSize: 10,}}> Release Date: {details.release_date} </Text>

          </View>

          
          </View>
          
           
         <View style={{marginLeft:15, zIndex:1  , marginBottom:50, marginLeft:20}} >
          <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize:16, fontWeight:'bold'  , marginBottom: 1,marginLeft: -5}} > Overview </Text>
          <Text style={{color: 'white',
    fontSize: 12, width:330, marginBottom:15}}>{details.overview}</Text>
    <TrendingPeople
            title="Actors"
                        navigation={props.navigation}
            url={`/movie/${props.route.params.movieId}/credits`}
            isForPage="details"
          />
          <View style={{marginLeft: -15, marginTop:10, }} >
<TrendingMovies
            title="SIMILAR MOVIES"
            navigation={props.navigation}
            url={`/movie/${props.route.params.movieId}/similar`}
/>
     </View>
        
          
          </View>

          </View>
          </ImageBackground>
         </ScrollView>
            </View>

      )}
    </View>
  );
};



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sectionBg: {
    backgroundColor: Constants.baseColor,
    height: deviceHeight,
    flex:1
  },
  trendingPeopleImage: {
    height: 70,
    width: 70,
    borderRadius: 500,
  },
  trendingPeopleName: {
    width: 60,
    color: Constants.textColor,
    fontSize: 12,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  trendingPeopleContainer: {
    margin: 10,
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: 'white',
    margin: 10,
    fontWeight:'bold'
  },
  posterImage: {
    height: 800,
    width: 150,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  movieTitle: {
    color: Constants.textColor,
    width: 150,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 5,
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight:'bold'
  },
  imageBg: {
 
position: 'absolute', top:0, left:0 ,
   width: deviceWidth,
    height: 400,
    opacity: 0.8
  },
  detailsMovieTitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    width: 180,
        fontWeight:'bold',
    color: 'white',
    marginLeft:15,
    marginTop: 35

  },
  linkContainer: {
    backgroundColor: Constants.secondaryColor,
    borderRadius: 100,
    padding: 10,
    width: 45,
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginTop: -20,
  },
  overview: {
    color: 'white',
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    textAlign: 'justify',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  details: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 11,
    marginLeft: 10,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  detailsContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    marginLeft:15
  },
  genreContainer: {

    borderColor: Constants.textColor,
    paddingHorizontal: 0,

  },
  genre: {
    width: 50,
    marginHorizontal:-5,
  fontWeight:'bold',fontWeight:'bold',
    color: '#C3C3C3',
    marginRight:4,
    fontSize: 9,
  },
   image : {
      height: 100,
      width: 180,
      borderRadius: 15,
      paddingHorizontal: 5,
      marginTop: 10,
      marginLeft: 20
  },
  Text: {
    marginLeft: 20,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 20
  },
  title: {
    marginTop: 10,
    width: 150,
    textAlign: 'center', 
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 12
  }
});

export default MovieDetails;```
````

Answer (score 0):

First you create a favorite state

```
const [ favorites, setFavorites ] = useState([]);
```

Then you use useEffect to load the favorite from async storage.

```
const getData = async () => {
   try {
       const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_key')
       if(value !== null) {
          setFavorites(JSON.parse('@storage_key'));
       }
   } catch(e) {
      // error reading value
   }
}

useEffect(() => {
     getData();
}, [])
```

Then you create a touchable component to add to favorites.

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addToFavorites('some_id')}>
     Add to Favorites
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Create the add to favorite function

```
 const addToFavorites = async (id) => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_key', JSON.stringify([...favorites, id]))
    setFavorites([...favorites, id]);

 }
```

More on Asyncstorage usage here - https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage

Comment: Thank you for the reponse, ur solution it almost worked, but when i refresh or i go to another movie , the movies that saved, disappear

Comment: if you copy/paste my code, then there's a typo in `@storage_key` in the getData function. You will need to correct it. I've amended my code.

Comment: I apologize for disturbing, i replaced the key @storage_key with normal text as 'hello' , but nothing has changed, is there any problem in my Favourites Flatlist?

Comment: i forgot to set addtofavorite functions as a async function, and add await to setItem. Please try amending your codes and see if it works.

Comment: i'm sorry, but i'm totaly amateur about react native and i dont know what to add in addToFavorites function

Comment: AddToFavorite function simply adds the movie's `id` to the favourites array, and store it in AsyncStorage